# Search for users on Ejabberd2 using smack, fails

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, ejabberd

Server: ejabberd2
XMPP:  smack 3.3.1

The goal is to design a chat engine. The user, by entering a username should be able to find out if the entered username is registered on the server.

[The Smack Javadocs can be found here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html)

- I am using UserSearch classes found in the Smack library.
- I can connect to the server.
- I can login using a username and password.
- I can add/sign up new users into the server.

I want to find if a username already exists on the server. The code that I have used and its respective error that I got are given below.

```
UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection);
Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search."+connection.getServiceName());
Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm(); 
answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);  
answerForm.setAnswer("search", name);

ReportedData data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm,"search."+connection.getServiceName());
```

The above code outputs the following error:

```
service-unavailable(503)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.UserSearch.getSearchForm(UserSearch.java:84)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.UserSearchManager.getSearchForm(UserSearchManager.java:73)
at com.phanism.www.XmppConnect.searchUser(XmppConnect.java:74)
at com.phanism.www.XmppConnect.main(XmppConnect.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the username you want to search.

```
erSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection);
Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search."+connection.getServiceName());
Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm(); 
answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);  
answerForm.setAnswer("search", name);//Here username must be added name replace by "amith"
```

Then it will work.. :)

Comment: in jabbered it fails.this solution just work in Openfire