# How to configure search service url for ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, smack, asmack

Following the directions from this answer: [Search for users on Ejabberd2 using smack, fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808663/search-for-users-on-ejabberd2-using-smack-fails)

I tried with my own ejabberd+asmack setup but continue to get

> service-unavailable (503)

response. Its possible it has something to do with the `searchService` argument of `UserSearchManager.getSearchForm(String searchService)` 
For an ejabberd server, from where do I figure out or configure the url for `searchService`?

Answer (score 1):

instead of "search."+ connection.getServiceName() use "vjud."+connection.getServiceName().